# Does dua really work?

Tags: dua

My brother who's been making dua for 10 years, day and night, for a cure and nothing has changed so he said to me he will never make dua again as it's a waste of time.  He said "I wasted all that time and tears for nothing...."

My question is: Can anyone prove to me dua really works?

Because God said call me and I will answer. Islam is confusing and don't tell me there's three ways of answering dua.

Comment: How can it be a waste of time to speak to your Lord? Your brother's wish to do dua and his patience and endurance to do it for 10 years was Allah's answer to him already. Allah swt kept him going to do it. For sure it was not in vain even though Allah swt has not fulfilled his wish. Never lose hope and never stop asking Allah for your needs.

Comment: First dua has some kind of rulings, how to perform it, when it's best to perform it etc. than Allah may answer a dua for some reasons (fastly) and may not or delay answering for some reasons, maybe it would even be for the best of your brother. So as it seems this is also a test for your brothers faith...

Answer (score 2):

Obviously dua is helpful dear brother. Allah knows best what is good for you and what bad for you. Allah will give you the things which are good for you.  If you make a good dua but don't get the thing you ask for, Allah will give it to you in Jannah and it will be at the highest level.  So don't limit yourself when ask anything to Allah because Allah becomes happy if asked for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Dua is the most powerful thing which have power even to change our Fate. And being disappointed is not good. Dua is the most useful way to get all your wishes and to make your life easier. So if you or your brother try to get your cure by making a dua then it will be fruitful and will give you a response at right time. Its just about checking and trying your patience and if you acquired that position then you will be rewarded with more even that you wouldn't think.  So be patience and never ever lose hope specially in that case if you are making a dua to Allah Almighty. And never think that He Almighty don't listen you. He can listen the vibration of leaves then how can he forget you (Ashraf-Ul-Makhloqat) it's not possible. So keep making Dua to Allah Almighty and gave some hopeful opinions to your brother also. God will bless you In Sha Allah.

Answer (score -2):

I already said duas will be addressed either in this world or in the after life or in paradise.  If you think your brother didn’t get what he was looking for, making duas for 10 years, then it must be something he had done, some kind of sin in a previous life and he is paying his debts in this life.  And of course with Allah or any gods, by showing devotion now he has made his future towards light either in this world or for his next life.  For example, he might have been a very lazy person in previous life, who did noting good and neither believed in God. So in this life he was praying for duas. After 10 years and he still didn't get any duas answered, if he thinks so then he might start new search for his cure.  That makes him take towards the light of knowledge. Thus Allah or God might have planned to make rid of his previous sin in this life in such way that he will be devoted to God and also gain self enlightenment.